# What surname would be changed to Yaver from Poland or Russia?

Tags: surnames, poland, russia

I am trying to trace the Yaver family backwards from New York to where they emigrated from Poland. I can't find any passenger lists or immigration paperwork for the surname Yaver (given name Isador or Isidor). I tried Yarer, Yavor, Yarar - I still come up with nothing.

I have tried JRI-Poland with no results. The census records list either Poland or Russia as their country of origin.

Comment: If [this](https://www.findagrave.com/memorial/97836736) is his grave stone photo on Findagrave, then it has his father's name in Hebrew.

Comment: What specifically do you have on the family in the U.S,?

Comment: @Xanne I see 1920 U.S. Census https://www.familysearch.org/search/ark:/61903/1:1:MJR3-ZDT , 1940 https://www.familysearch.org/search/ark:/61903/1:1:K3YZ-W2D , 1950 https://www.familysearch.org/search/ark:/61903/1:1:6XPW-KV5K ...

Answer (score 1):

familysearch shows some people with the surname "Jawor" born in Poland, eg. Isidorus Jawor, Izydorus Jawor, as well as the cyrillic "явор" and some other similar? names "Zaver", "Xavier", "Ljavor"

Answer (score 1):

In several Slavic languages and dialects "yavor/yawor" means [maple tree](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Slavic/avor%D1%8A#Descendants), so family names along the lines of Jawor/Yavorchuk/Jaworski/Yavorofsky/Yaverbaum are quite common in Eastern Europe. I'd guess, [Isadore](https://www.ancestry.com/family-tree/person/tree/189572833/person/292477930555) could have Americanized his from any one of those.

For example, here is a mention of [Isidor Jaworski](https://www.familysearch.org/search/ark:/61903/1:1:QGGL-Z13S). "New York Passenger Arrival Lists (Ellis Island), 1892-1924", database with images, FamilySearch (https://familysearch.org/ark:/61903/1:1:QGGL-Z13S : 2 March 2021), Isidor Jaworski in entry for Anna Berdechowska, 1907. Perhaps it is him, but perhaps not, as this name is quite common.